# SharePoint 2016 in office 365 (out of curiosity)

Tags: office-365, 2016

Does anyone has idea when is SP 2016 coming to Office 365.

Answer (score 4):

What I am sure Sharepoint online already advanced to Sharepoint 2016. You can check the version number and confirm it. Use this blog:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/fromthefield/2016/01/07/quickly-verify-the-version-of-a-sharepoint-online-tenant/

With popularity of 365, MSFt release the new versions / features to Sharepoint online 1st then bring to on prem. I.e. Teams are available in 365 but not reached to on prem yet.

Comment: It's the cloud first, mobile first approach where new functionalities is developed on the cloud first - and via feature packs to on premise. +1

Comment: "SharePoint Online" suggest latest SharePoint version, and the on-premise version get named "SharePoint 2016" and counting, and updates come in the form of SP to catch up to the new features in the Online version. Also the article linked above, for the sake of the archive here on stack, you can also get the version information by going to (thanks to Brodie for posting it in the comment section on that blog): https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_vti_pvt/service.cnf

Comment: then in that case, what is reason behind showing "2013 experience version will be used" under template selection while creating site collections in SPO. Is it a mistake from MSFT ??

Comment: Because there is no "2016 experience" in this context.  The on-prem version of 2016 also doesn't have that option.

Comment: It is but it is what it is